# Present Perfect with "one of these days"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, present-perfect

I was going to ask a question on Stack Overflow, and start it like so:

> One of these days I've run into an issue, where...

But then I thought, is this really okay to use Present Perfect with "one of these days"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're correct to think that this would sound odd; as a colloquial expression, the phrase "one of these days" means "[at some time in the future](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/one%20of%20these%20days)." (Of course, there are circumstances in which the words "one of these days" can be used to mean something else, but it's clear that that isn't what you are asking about.)

I wonder if perhaps what you want to say is "I've [recently](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recently) run into an issue…"

Edit: As @TypeIA mentions in a comment, "in the last few days" or "in the past few days" would work, too – assuming the event to which you're referring is in fact that recent.

Comment: That's strange, I was sure it's commonly used to talk about the past, like "one of the past few days." But you seem to be right :) And yes, I basically meant "recently." Can you perhaps think of any other way to put it into words? Can I use "one of the past few days" here? But if so, I've probably got to use the past tense since the days have already passed.

Comment: You may be looking for "in the **last** (or **past**) few days, I've run into an issue..."

Comment: @TypeIA, thanks – I've added that to my answer. X-yuri, you can still use the present perfect if the "issue" you're referring to is still causing you trouble in the present. If it has been resolved, "a few days ago" and the simple past tense would be more natural: "A few days ago I ran into an issue." (And if it has been resolved, simple past works better with "recently," too: "Recently I ran into an issue…")

Comment: +1; my comment was directed at x-yuri, just to clarify. I forgot to @tag.

Comment: It should be *One **day I ran** into an issue where . . .* or *One of these days **I will** run into an issue where . . .* There is insufficient context in the question to determine the desired tense.